# 2D Array assign problem VHDL having different size

Tags: arrays, 2d, vhdl, assignment-operator

I have two 2D arrays defined as below

```vhdl
type ram_1300_block is array (1300 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

type ram_2700_block is array (2700 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

rx_ram : ram_1300_block;
Q1_ram : ram_2700_block;
```

Then I am using the below assignment statement in my code:

```
Q1_ram(1300 downto 1) <= rx_ram(1341 downto 42);
```

While synthesizing I am getting the below error in vivado 2015.3

```
Synth 8-2234 indexed name is not a ram_3700 block?
```

Any workaround?

I dont want to increase the small array size due to resource constraint.

Comment: These are not 2d arrays.  They are 1d arrays of a 1d array type

Comment: Note that assigning practically an entire RAM to another one in a single assignment statement will be fine in simulation, but will synthesise to lousy hardware (over 10,000 FFs)

Answer (score 1):

This is because VHDL is a stronly typed language. Here `rx_ram` and `Q1_ram` are different types, and hence cannot be directly assigned to one another. Even more difficult, because you have assigned a size to your types, you cannot do a type conversion because the slices have no distinct type that can be named for a closely related type conversion.

I recommend you create a type that is unconstrained, that is constrained when you create the signals, and hence can be assigned to one another. You can even create named subtypes if you wish:

```
type ram_block_t is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
subtype ram_1300_block is ram_block_t(1300 downto 0);
subtype ram_2700_block is ram_block_t(2700 downto 0);

signal rx_ram : ram_2700_block ;
signal Q1_ram : ram_1300_block;

Q1_ram(1300 downto 1) <= rx_ram(1341 downto 42);
```

Note1: I assumed you had the types wrong in your original post, as `rx_ram(1341 downto 42)` uses index that are out of range for the type.

Note2: The names of the signals and types are likely bad, as I do not know any tool that will infer RAM with such large assignments.

Comment: Using natural worked. Thanks a lot.